# Coherence theorem in a lax monoidal category without unit

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am currently trying to understand the coherence theorem in monoidal categories. I would like to understand (in terms similar to those used in MacLane's theorem 3.1 in https://inspirehep.net/files/1e02ad81af7a278f19b217e99715a973 or in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mac+Lane%27s+proof+of+the+coherence+theorem+for+monoidal+categories) what would happen, if we removed the condition that the associators are isomorphisms and just ask that they are simple morphisms. It should yield something like a lax monoidal category without unit (I don't care about the unit object).

More precisely, let $X$ be a category with a bifunctor $\otimes: X \times X \rightarrow X$ and a natural transformation $\alpha: (- \otimes -) \otimes - \rightarrow - \otimes (- \otimes -)$ that obeys the usual pentagon identity. We can regard the set of possible bracketings on $n$ objects as partially ordered ($A \leq B$ if and only if $A$ can be transformed into $B$ by "associating to the right") turning it into a thin category $\mathcal{B}_n$. The goal is now to construct a functor $\mathcal{B}_n \rightarrow Hom(X^{\times n}, X)$ sending brackets to $\otimes$ and "associating to the right" to $\alpha$. If such a functor exists, we have shown the coherence theorem. The crucial point is that there are many ways to obtain a bracketing $B$ from a bracketing $A$ by applying associators.

In his proof MacLane shows by induction on the rank of the bracketing that the transformation required to go between two such bracketings is either possible by naturality, functioriality or the pentagon identity. However, in order to apply the induction hypothesis it is required to have an arrow $M \rightarrow H_{(n)}$ (notation from the proof):

[image: maclane proof diagram]

Assuming invertibility (or at least the left cancellation property) for this associator, he can conclude that the arrows on the left and right to the final object yield the same natural transformation of functors. In the "lax case" as described here, this "trick" does not work. What we would need is something like this:

Let $A_0 \leq A_i \leq A_\infty$, $i=1,2$ objects in $\mathcal{B}_n$ with the first relations being "elementary", i.e., they involve just one associator. Then, there exists a bracketing $Z$, s.t. $A_i \leq Z \leq A_\infty$ and $Z$ is minimal among such $Z$, in which case the diamond $A_0 \leq A_i \leq Z$ will commute (after applying the functor) by functoriality of $\otimes$, naturality of $\alpha$ and by the pentagon identity. So we can proceeed as in MacLane's proof.

My question is now: How do we prove the existence of such a $Z \leq A_\infty$?

(My assumption: $Z$ must be of the same shape as in the original proof. How does $Z \leq A_\infty$ follow?)

Do you know of any papers that discuss this setup?